# Loop to create option data in php

Tags: php

**Data**

```
    Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => USPS First Class Package (2 To 3 business days)
                    [value] => USPSFirstClass
                    [category] => STANDARD
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => USPS Priority Mail (1 To 3 business days)
                    [value] => USPSPriority
                    [category] => EXPEDITED
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                   [name] => FedEx Ground or FedEx Home Delivery (1 To 5 
 business days)
                   [value] => FedExHomeDelivery
                   [category] => STANDARD
        )

            [3] => Array
              (
                  [name] => UPS Ground (1 To 5 business days)
                  [value] => UPSGround
                  [category] => EXPEDITED
              )

        )
```

Question: The above data I want to loop it as a dropdown list with optgroup label. The dropdown data will be show as

**STANDARD**

USPS First Class Package (2 To 3 business days)

FedEx Ground or FedEx Home Delivery (1 To 5 
     business days)

**EXPEDITED**

USPS Priority Mail (1 To 3 business days)

UPS Ground (1 To 5 business days)

How can I do that :(

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Downvoted because no coding attempt. Voted to close as Too Broad.

Comment: A quick google will give you some inspiration.  Such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876224/create-an-optgroup-from-an-array-of-data and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40787238/php-create-the-optgroups-based-on-the-value-of-an-array and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215937/drop-down-option-groups-from-multiple-php-arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
<?php

$data = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'USPS First Class Package (2 To 3 business days)',
        'value' => 'USPSFirstClass',
        'category' => 'STANDARD'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'USPS Priority Mail (1 To 3 business days)',
        'value' => 'USPSPriority',
        'category' => 'EXPEDITED'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'FedEx Ground or FedEx Home Delivery (1 To 5 business days)',
        'value' => 'FedExHomeDelivery',
        'category' => 'STANDARD'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'UPS Ground (1 To 5 business days)',
        'value' => 'UPSGround',
        'category' => 'EXPEDITED'
    ),
);
```

Sort your categories into one array:

```
$sorted = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value){
    $sorted[$value['category']][] = array($value['name'], $value['value']);
}
```

and loop through it:

```
echo "<select>";
foreach ($sorted as $key => $value){
    echo "<optgroup label='$key'>";
    foreach ($value as $v){
        echo "<option value='". $v[1]."'>". $v[0] ."</option>";
    }
    echo "</optgroup>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
<?php
$data = [
    [
        'name' => 'USPS First Class Package (2 To 3 business days)',
        'value' => 'USPSFirstClass',
        'category' => 'STANDARD'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'USPS Priority Mail (1 To 3 business days)',
        'value' => 'USPSPriority',
        'category' => 'EXPEDITED'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'FedEx Ground or FedEx Home Delivery (1 To 5
 business days)',
        'value' => 'FedExHomeDelivery',
        'category' => 'STANDARD'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'UPS Ground (1 To 5 business days)',
        'value' => 'UPSGround',
        'category' => 'EXPEDITED'
    ]
];

function _group_by($array, $key)
{
    $return = array();
    foreach ($array as $val) {
        $return[$val[$key]][] = $val;
    }

    return $return;
}

$result = _group_by($data, 'category');
?>

<select>
    <?php foreach ($result as $key => $value): ?>
        <optgroup label="<?php echo $key ?>">
            <?php foreach ($value as $v): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $v['value'] ?>"><?php echo $v['name'] ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </optgroup>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

this `_group_by` function separate your array based on your key

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

1)Create array for standard and expedited values

```
$standard=array();
$expedited=array();
```

2)Loop through your arrays

```
foreach($array_1 as $k=>$v) {
    if($v['category'] == 'STANDARD'){
        array_push($standard,$v['name']);
    }
    if($v['category'] == 'EXPEDITED'){
        array_push($expedited,$v['name']);
    }
}
```

3)Print what you need

```
print("STANDARD");
print nl2br("\n");
foreach($standard as $s){
    print_r($s);
    print nl2br("\n");
}

print nl2br("\n");
print("EXPEDITED");
print nl2br("\n");
foreach($expedited as $e){
    print($e);
    print nl2br("\n");
}
```

Final output will be:

```
STANDARD
USPS First Class Package (2 To 3 business days)
FedEx Ground or FedEx Home Delivery (1 To 5 )

EXPEDITED
USPS Priority Mail (1 To 3 business days)
UPS Ground (1 To 5 business days)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can sort it by category using [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) function

and then loop through.